# Unable to readvalue from html string using objectmapper

Tags: java, fasterxml

```
public void testJson() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String htmlString = mapper.readValue("<!Doctype>", String.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
>   ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array,
>   object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source: (String)"";

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Look closer at the error. `JsonParseException`. HTML is not JSON.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Yes correct. I posted the answer. Please review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using gson.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: Sure, that will work, I guess. I'm not sure how this is useful for anything though. Maybe [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is what you want.